# Using the value of OptionValue to clear a list

Tags: list-manipulation, options, attributes

I'm currently using `OptionValue` inside a function, the `Option` I passed to the function should be cleared, then populated with the result of other operations inside the function. Creating the list and filling it now works given that it is an empty list. Clearing the list does not. I found some surprising behaviour when investigating why it wouldn't work. So suppose I look at the following:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Options[foo] = {OutputList -> Empty};



foo[OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{bar, Output},
  (* output roots *)
  bar = {1,5,10,300};

  Output = OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, OutputList, Hold];
  Head[OptionValue[OutputList]];
  Clear[OptionValue[OutputList]];

  If[Output =!= Hold@Empty,
   Output /. Hold[o_] :> (o = bar);,
   bar]
  ]
```

We can see that when `OptionValue[somevalue]` is called, it is a symbol. But when trying to clear it, suddenly it is not a symbol anymore. I've tried various `Hold` constructs, but I couldn't make anything sensical out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see how [`OptionValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html) is transformed by wrapping it in [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html):

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{bar, Output},
    Hold[Clear[OptionValue[OutputList]]]
  ]

foo[]
```

> ```
> Hold[Clear[OptionValue[foo, {}, OutputList]]]
> ```

`OptionValue[foo, {}, OutputList]` is not a Symbol and cannot be cleared.  A simple way to do this is to [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) `Clear` to `Hold[symbol]`.  I think you want something like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Options[foo] = {OutputList -> Empty};

foo[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{bar, Output},(*output roots*)bar = {1, 5, 10, 300};
  Output = OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, OutputList, Hold];
  If[Output =!= Hold@Empty,
   Clear @@ Output; Output /. Hold[o_] :> (o = bar);, bar]]

(* note use of RuleDelayed to pass the output Symbol *)
foo[OutputList :> store];

(* check contents of store *)
store
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 10, 300}
> ```

You might not actually need that as `o = bar` will reassign a basic [`OwnValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html) assignment without the need to Clear first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your last solution, but I'm still getting error messages, in the case where bar is a list.

Comment: In the actual function the exact output is:

Comment: During evaluation of In[1342]:= Clear::ssym: {-3.14226,-2.90282,-2.84296,-2.7831,-2.72324,-2.66338,-2.60353,-2.54367,<<35>>,-0.0300119,<<50>>} is not a symbol or a string.
During evaluation of In[1342]:= Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object -3.14226.
During evaluation of In[1342]:= Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object -2.90282.
During evaluation of In[1342]:= Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object -2.84296.
During evaluation of In[1342]:= General::stop: Further output of Set::setraw will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: @101 Please notice that I pass the option value using `:>` rather than `->`; using the latter would lead to the kind of error you quote.  I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Yes, I believe omitting `RuleDelayed` was the problem... Cheers